# How to Count the number of document in a particular collection in firestore flutter and display at Scaffold Text widget

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to display the no. of documents in collection in Realtime.[In image 4 document][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLiDy.jpg

```js
 countDocuments() async {
    QuerySnapshot _myDoc = await collectionReference.get();
    List myDocCount = _myDoc.docs;
    var totalStudent = myDocCount.length.toString();
    return print(totalStudent);
  }
```

In above code when I called countDocument() function in raised button or any button type it print the total document present in collection in DEBUG CONSOLE of VS code BUT **I want to display this No. in inside of Scaffold's Text() widget**.
So, how I Can display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is an async operation, you can use a `FutureBuilder` to wrap the `Text` widget and use it in the `Scaffold`.

```dart
     FutureBuilder(
        future: collectionReference.get(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
           if (snapshot.hasData) {
             List myDocCount = snapshot.data.docs;
             var totalStudent = myDocCount.length.toString();
             return Text(totalStudent.toString());
           } else {
             return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
           }
        },
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

simply you can do like that
**text:Text("${totalStudent}"),**

Comment: **error :** Undefined name 'totalStudent'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.